# svn diff | view - How to highlight changes character-based instead of only line-based?

Tags: svn, vim, diff

Right now I use `svn diff | vim -` to get a colorized output. Alas, only the changed lines get highlighted, but I want to instantly see the characters I changed as well.

I want an effect like github is offering, e.g. [like this diff](https://github.com/torvalds/subsurface/compare/7b5874ead7...513df18f50#diff-1).

kompare seems quite powerful, but I'd prefer a console-tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [`kompare`](http://www.caffeinated.me.uk/kompare/). It's great to me.

Example usage:

```
$ svn di > name.diff
$ kompare name.diff
```

It highlights the words, too. It's free, beautiful and easy to use :)

Comment: Actually kompare supports reading stdin as far as I know (an extremely nice feature), so you could simplify to `svn diff | kompare -`.

Comment: @hlovdal - by the way, I tried this and it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

There's been [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625/best-diff-tool) about diff viewers. It might help you to review and choose appropriate one.

[TkDiff](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tkdiff/) and [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) can highlight words.

Comment: KDiff3 is awesome, and I use it all the time.